# Delaunay triangulation in 3D

Tags: coordinates, mesh, triangulation, delaunay

How would I implement Delaunay triangulation in three dimensions and aside from that, would this be efficient for plotting graphs in spherical coordinates? (If not, do you know of a more efficient method? Thanks.)

Also, are there any disadvantages for 3D surface mesh generation with Delaunay triangulation(s)?

Thank-you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try Bowyer-Watson algorithm but with tetrahedrons or you could try to lift the points to a paraboloid:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200536/3d-delaunay-triangulation-by-4d-paraboloids.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **libdts2** for a spherical delaunay triangulation.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45240506/4994003